# Disable wifi password remembering in windows 7

Tags: windows-7-x64

I'd like to disable password remembering in windows 7 in laptop. What I have done is that I have deleted wifi name in settings of network from list. Now I have to connect manualy with this network but windows still remembers password.

How to force it to ask every time for the network password? Can someone write step by step what should I do etc.? I'm getting nervous about it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open User Accounts by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking User Accounts and Family Safety (or clicking User Accounts, if you are connected to a network domain), and then clicking User Accounts.
2. In the left pane, click Manage your network passwords.
3. Click the password that you want to remove, and then click Remove.

Comment: Problem solved. I had to change wifi SSID to another and disable connect automatically with network.